# JDialog - Add and arrange buttons

Tags: java, jbutton, jdialog

I have this code where I add 9 buttons, but I want them to appear in 3 different lanes (3 buttons for each row) but I do not know how to, any suggestions?

```
...

JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();

//JButton1
JButton jButton1 = new JButton("OK");
jButton1.setText("Package 1");
jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});
buttonPane.add(jButton1);

//JButton2
JButton jButton2 = new JButton("OK");
jButton2.setText("Package 2");
jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});
buttonPane.add(jButton2);

//JButton3
...
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `GridLayout` layout manager.

**For Example:**

```
buttonPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, cols));
```

Read more a bout [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class ButtonGrid 
 {
     JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
     public ButtonGrid() 
     {
         buttonPane .setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
         buttonPane.add(new Button("1"));
         buttonPane.add(new Button("2"));
         buttonPane.add(new Button("3"));
         buttonPane.add(new Button("4"));
         buttonPane.add(new Button("5"));
         buttonPane.add(new Button("6"));
         buttonPane.add(new Button("7"));
         buttonPane.add(new Button("8"));
         buttonPane.add(new Button("9"));
     }
 }
```

Try this code sample